# How to hide title bar from webpage and run in full screen in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

I built a basic application in asp.net in which I want to implement a web page which runs in full screen mode, which means without title and any bar.
I tried more but I could not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should work for you ,

```
<head>  
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function max() 
        { 
            var obj = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.shell"); 
            obj.SendKeys("{f11}"); 
        } 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body onload="javascript:max()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Keep in mind that in many is no possible to hide the adress bar for security reasons I believe.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function fullScreen(theURL) {
window.open(theURL, '', 'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=auto');
}
</script>
</head>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fullScreen('http://google.com');">
Full Screen Window
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```